# Vuex use keys to access object in state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have code like this for a store in Vuex, if do it like the code below it works fine.

```
state: {
    APIData: {},
},
getters: {
    getFeed: state => {return state.APIData },
},
mutations: {
    SET_FEED_DATA(state, {folder_id, data}) {
        state.APIData = data
    }
},
```

However, if I try to use a key to set and get the value it return `undefined` in the getter. I want to do this because I have a for loop in my template calling an action multiple times but with different id's that I will use here for the key value.

```
state: {
    APIData: {},
},
getters: {
    getFeed: state => {return state.APIData["test"] },
},
mutations: {
    SET_FEED_DATA(state, {folder_id, data}) {
        state.APIData["test"] = data
    }
},
```

**Edit**

Looking in Vue debugger I find the following, so it seems the mutation is setting that data but the getter can access it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the mutation, try to set it like below:

```js
state.APIData = { ...state.APIData, test: data };
```

The getter is for `APIData` and it will not recognize the change if you update an individual property directly. You need to reset the whole `APIData` object.

To replace the test with a variable:

```js
state.APIData = { ...state.APIData, [VARIABLE_NAME]: data };
```

For example, if you want to pass the key name as `folder_id` in your code:

```js
state.APIData = { ...state.APIData, [folder_id]: data };
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, I provided "test" like an example, in my actuall code "test" would be replaced by a varaible. Do you know any way to do the same thing by with a variable value.